# Is users' discussion/chat on Jailbreaking allowed in an Apple-approved app?

Tags: iphone, applications, jailbreak, ios-appstore

We have a 'web service' iPhone app where users can generate new content (which is publicly viewable) by uploading texts.

So, wanted to confirm: is it okay if they discuss/chat on benefits or on how to jailbreak?

Will the Apple take action once they find out? Or considering it to be user generated content, it will be ignored?

EDIT:
The app is not specifically meant for discussing Jailbreak. The app has many categories, including a "general chat" category, where it is being discussed by the users.

Answer (score 5):

Unless Apple is hosting the user-generated content and the discussion of jailbreaking is in violation of the terms of use of that site, I don't see how Apple *could* take any action  against such a discussion.

There are certainly people using various Facebook, Twitter, and other public communication apps on their iPhones to discuss jailbreaking.

Comment: seems reasonable enough!... but still waiting for more +1 on your answer!

Comment: @Tajar, if you're making a portal to allow jailbreakers to communicate with each other, Apple will not approve the app. Jailbreaking has not been deemed illegal, but it is in violation of the terms of use that Apple has set out (it also voids your warranty and bars you from receiving any kind of support). They will reject it on those grounds, not on legality. Moreover, Apple will likely not allow any kind of app that endorses or promotes this activity grace their App Store on those same grounds.

Comment: @cksum: If you meant that our app is specifically meant for discussing JB, it is not the case... We have many categories, including a "general chat" category, where it is being discussed by the users. (Updated the question to include the same.)

Comment: @Tajar, I'd say you are likely fine so long as the app itself does not contain any reference to jailbreaking. They have approved the Opera browser and a user can certainly use it find information about jailbreaking. Provided you don't have an explicit category called "Jailbreaking", I don't see Apple rejecting it on those grounds.